# How to set cookie_path in Zend Framework 1 application.ini?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've set the following in my application.ini config file:

```
resources.session.cookie_domain = ".app.mydomain.com"
```

Then, in my Bootstrap file I've got:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initSession()
    {
        Zend_Session::start();
    }
.
.
.
```

As far as I can see, this config isn't being picked up.

If I try:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initSession()
    {
        ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.app.mydomain.com');
    }
.
.
.
```

...It works! But clearly this is just a hack. What do I need to do to have ZF pick up my config setting? I can confirm that when I dump out the config options, I can see my config setting, it just seems it's not being applied to the session.

Comment: What if you bootstrap your session resource first? Like `$this->bootstrap('session');`?

Comment: Where do I put that? I replaced the `Zend_Session::start();` with `$this->bootstrap('session');` and I get an error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Circular resource dependency detected' in /var/www/vhosts/qasystem/qasystem/library/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php`. My collegue also suggestion that. If possible, could you reply to this question as an answer with an example?

Comment: provided the complete answer